# Website works on Laptop Browser but does not work on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-website, mern

I have developed a web app using the MERN stack.
This website is: [www.javascriptmazes.com](https://www.javascriptmazes.com) .  For some reason when I open that link on my Laptop's browser, everything works as expected.  However when I try to open the same website on my mobile (Samsung) phone the page does not load properly and I end up seeing just the white background of the browser.

I don't know exactly how to debug on mobile phones since I always do my debugging on my laptop.
However I went to this website https://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ and tried to load the said web link on  the emulator and the error messages displayed are:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.javascriptmazes.com/static/css/main.1e4202c6.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>   emulate.php?url=http%3A//javascriptmazes.com&user_agent=Mozilla/6.0 (iPhone%3B CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML%2C like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25&device=Apple-Iphone6:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.javascriptmazes.com/static/js/main.5d7eb463.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How do I serve content through HTTPS? and How do I know which specific content needs to be changed?

I'm using MERN....so my client side uses React....also if you look at the web app I use alot of HTML canvas and scripts to draw on the HTML canvas....I don't know if that is relevant or not but just wanted to mention it just in case...

HOw to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you not just update the url that points to the HTTP resource to use HTTPS

Comment: In Chrome I get the white page too `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at redux.js:604
    at i (redux.js:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (store.js:34)
    at t (bootstrap a926ca3834f103a1b3df:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (App.js:13)
    at t (bootstrap a926ca3834f103a1b3df:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at t (bootstrap a926ca3834f103a1b3df:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.5d7eb463.js:71)
    at t (bootstrap a926ca3834f103a1b3df:19)`

Comment: It works on my Chrome on my laptop .....

Comment: Agree with Roland that you should check out the console error. My guess is this error is preventing other things from loading. Checking the HTML, the only non-script in the <body> is `<div id="root"></div>` (i.e. no content).

Comment: How to reproduce your error @RolandStarke ?  I also use Chrome but it works on my Laptop using CHrome....for both http and https....

Comment: @preston Windows 10, Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90

Comment: What browsers are you using, please include version and OS. (Chrome on Mac OS/iOS is not proper chrome)

Comment: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6's Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Ah, the difference is probably down to Blink vs WebKit... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350674

Comment: I also just downloaded Firefox on Mac and it works there too...

Comment: I don't own a mac, but as far as i know, every browser is forced to use the same rendering engine on iOS. So using firefox/chrome/safari won't make a difference.

Comment: Hi I think I've solved the problem...pls see answer below...it is already working on my Samsung Smartphone...how about on your end?  Thank you...I will try to test it on Windows 10 Chrome when I find another computer with that OS....

Comment: Works here too now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the problem.
Redux Dev Tools were causing the problem.
I changed it from:

```
var store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      initialState,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

      )
     );
```

to:

```
var store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      initialState,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
      )
     );
```

and it works on my mobile phone now....

Answer (score 1):

The white page you see on your phone (Samsung) is what people are seeing in Chrome on Windows. I would learn how to use [remote debugging tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) rather than try to use an emulator.